# CodeIgniter: pagination and retrieving stored query strings as arrays

Tags: codeigniter

I am implementing pagination and stored query strings in the db and I followed [nettut+ tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-search-results-without-query-strings-2/)

With some modifications, I am able to store arrays with keys and values:

```
$query_array = array(
    'age' => $this->input->post('age'),
    // checkboxes with name citizenship[]
    'Citizenship' => $this->input->post('citizenship'),
);
```

I looped through the POST array and assigned keys and values:

```
foreach($_POST['Citizenship'] as $k => $v) {
    $Citizenship[$v] = $v;
}
```

Now my stored query string carries arrays with keys and looks like this:

```
&age=18&Citizenship[0]=2&Citizenship[1]=4&Citizenship[2]=6
```

So far, everything works fine. But when I try to retrieve the stored query, I always get empty values to arrays:

```
&age=18&Citizenship[0]=&Citizenship[1]=&Citizenship[2]=
```

I have extended the input library with the load_query function:

```
function load_query($query_id) {

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $rows = $CI->db->get_where('bs_query', array('id' => $query_id))->result();
    if (isset($rows[0])) {
        parse_str($rows[0]->query_string, $_GET);       
    }
}
```

The `parse_str` does not return the values along with the arrays.

Any help appreciated..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. Just fetched the array as

> $varname =  $_GET[arrayname][index].